# Fix math mode kerning of "C"

Tags: microtype, kerning

I am trying to set a sequence of atom packing symbols.  I want to use math mode italics for this, as I think that their width fits this purpose.

The problem is that the *C* has a bad kerning for this.  There is a too large space after it.  How could I fix this?

I have tried to use the `microtype` package, but it seems to have no effect.  What am I doing wrong?  Do I have to specify the font in a more detailed manner?

```
\documentclass[pdftex,a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[kerning=allmath]{microtype}
\LoadMicrotypeFile{lmr}

\SetExtraKerning
  {encoding = *, shape = *}
  {C = {,-300}}

\begin{document}

$ABCBCBACAC$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\textit` in also math mode to get a kerning.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
\Huge
$ABCBCBACAC$

$\textit{ABCBCBACAC}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: huh, don't you mean `\mathit` not `\textit`

Comment: Thanks, but that produces text italics, which are a bit more narrow than math italics (for example, the angle of the _A_ is more acute).  The same holds for `\mathit`.  However, I guess that I will stick to that.

Comment: @daleif: no, I meant `\textit` otherwise I'd used `\mathit`