# Poor kerning with adjacent uppercase variables in math mode

Tags: math-mode, kerning

I want to lay out a sequence of adjacent variables in math-mode with reasonable spacing between the letters. But LaTeX produces output which (to me) is "obviously wrong":

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[B X A \Gamma C\]
\[B\;X\;A\;\Gamma\;C\]
\[B\;X\;A\;G\;C\]
\[B A \Gamma C\]
\end{document}
```

To clarify, I don't want these to appear as one word, but as consecutive variables, as in a product or curried function application.

What's going on here? X is clearly causing problems, but even in the last example the A looks slightly too close to the gamma and too far away from the B.

Why does LaTeX perform so badly on such a simple example, and how do I get better kerning by default?

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18373/fix-math-mode-kerning-of-c?rq=1) is related.

Comment: The middle two with hand spacing are bad, the top one looks about as good as can be expected with `XA` the bottom one isn't brilliant but there are no font-specified kerns between letters in different fonts, as is the case `\Gamma C`

Comment: @egreg Yes, I want the consecutive letters to scan visually like a product (possibly with a little extra spacing, as with the explicit `\;`). But I didn't understand your explanation about italic correction - if I was typesetting this out by hand I would place the A slightly to the left, even in the first case.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You seem to be saying that for the second example, the spacing is bad, but as good as can be expected. Well, I agree it's bad, but I expect better :)

Comment: @Mico Thanks, but that's not what I'm after; clarified the question accordingly.

Comment: No, I'm saying the 2nd and 3rd examples are bad spacing, the 1st and 4th are better, although probably I'd add a small space (much less than `\;`) after the gamma.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh, I see. Thanks for clarifying. I agree with your summary, then, except that I would shift the A to the left (by a similarly small amount) rather than adding space after the gamma in examples 1 and 4.

Comment: If the font doesn't have this info then LaTeX doesn't have much to do. Besides this is our brain failing to match the borders of X and A. Try `BX\!A\Gamma C`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `math kerning`, but its values will depend on the pair of letters, and probably on the math font that you use. How do you like this one:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[B X \mkern-1mu N \mkern-2mu A\mkern2mu Γ \mkern1mu C\]

\[B X \mkern-1mu A\mkern2mu Γ \mkern1mu C\]

\[B A\mkern2mu Γ \mkern-0.5muA\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your posted image doesn't match with the code you posted.

Comment: This is a significant improvement (but see comment above :)

Comment: You need to put the A and X in the given order

Comment: @Roly: Right, they correspond to two different attempts. I'll math them at once.

Comment: @percusse: Done. I wanted to draw attention to the fact that there were also problems with the letter `N`.